# Gnome desktop file does not run "java -jar" command

Tags: java, desktop-application, executable-jar, ubuntu-18.04, gnome

I wrote an application with JavaFX and I would like to run it like a "native" app in Ubuntu.

So I created the following desktop file and put it in `~/.local/share/applications`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Notes
Exec=java -jar /home/namhto/dev/Notes/build/libs/notes-1.0.0.jar
Icon=/home/namhto/dev/Notes/build/libs/icon.png
Type=Application
Terminal=false
```

The desktop icon is created but when launching it from the gnome desktop, nothing happens. Running the command `java -jar /home/namhto/dev/Notes/build/libs/notes-1.0.0.jar` from a terminal effectively starts my app.

I tried to mark the jar file as executable in Ubuntu but it does not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with using /the/absolute/path/to/java for your exec command (which you can find out via `which java` for example), instead of a relative one. Maybe your ENV setup doesn't have java in $PATH somehow.

Anything else looks good to me.

Comment: This was the solution thanks. I'm wondering why the terminal knows about the java command but not the desktop file tho.

Comment: @Namhto94 The terminal sources all kinds of init files, like .bashrc or others. Those files setup things like $PATH, so that you can invoke java without giving an absolute path. Most likely, the desktop is missing some/all of that setup.